# Python Auto-Start pyGSM Huawei

Tags: python, serial-port

I have a python script which uses pygsm as the library for sending and receiving sms. However, I wish to put this script on auto-run upon booting up the raspberry pi. But the connecting time of the huawei modem usually takes a while, hence causing the shell script to skip the step. How do I make it so that it would confirm that it is connected to perform the python script?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a python-related question, try a linux forum on boot sequence timeout